# Microsoft SmoothStreaming video on Apache?

Tags: apache, video, windows-phone-8, ffmpeg, smooth-streaming

I created what I consider to be a valid smooth streaming output using ffmpeg with the smooth streaming muxer and also alternatively through the ismindex utility (included in ffmpeg sources).

I'm trying to use an standard web server like Apache instead of IIS and its S.S. extensions. The output is segmented content (each fragment is split to is own file) so theoretically this is possible. Now comes my first problem where I'm stuck.

How can I test the result using for example a Window Phone 8?. I tried to open the index.ism url from I.Explorer, but the extension ism and the mime-type (application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml) is not recognized and I.Explorer just dump the xml instead of opening the media player.
 I was waiting for a similar behaviour to that of Android/iOS when the (HLS) index.m3u8 URL is clicked. In this case the browser/OS detects the extension and open the player.

Thanks in advance for any help, hint or link!